# How to save one graph in two destination files?

Tags: r, ggplot2

It saves "b.png", which is obvious. How to save both pdf and png?

```
pdf("a.pdf")
png("b.png")

plot(iris$Sepal.Length)

dev.off()
dev.off()
```

Comment: try `?dev.copy`

Comment: You can store the object and call it once for each file: `interesting.plot <- plot(iris$Sepal.Length); pdf("a.pdf"); interesting.plot; dev.off(); pdf("b.pdf"); interesting.plot; dev.off()`

Comment: @Llopis wouldn't work with base plot, maybe you meant with ggplot?

Comment: @zx8 Yes, the question is tagged for ggplot, but I wasn't aware it wouldn't work for the base plot :(

Comment: It is not working for any plot. I am OK with ggplot or base plot

Comment: @baptiste Would you mind adding as an answer (or edit existing), can't make it work with `dev.copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, we are assigning ggplot output into a variable then "plot" into files:

```
library(ggplot2)

myPlot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()

pdf("temp.pdf")
myPlot
dev.off()

png("temp.png")
myPlot
dev.off()
```

Or using for ggsave

```
myPlot
ggsave("temp.pdf")
ggsave("temp.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @baptiste's suggestion, this seems to work:

```
pdf("a.pdf")
dev.control(displaylist = "enable")

  plot(iris$Sepal.Length)
  plot(iris$Sepal.Width)

dev.copy(png, "b.png")
for (d in tail(dev.list(), 2)) dev.off(d)
```

Note that while the pdf gets both plots, only the most recent one lands in the png.

Comment: In general, the ask is to save all in one pdf and each individual in png

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about it with zx8 (the other answerer) and that's also what I'd like to know how to do.